# Why doesn't Visual Studio warn about a circular initialisation of a static string?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, static, initialization, circular-reference

A silly but probably not-so-uncommon error when I replaced a string literal by a static string was leading to something like the following code snippet which is probably almost never intended and trivial to spot, even for a machine:

```
public partial class T { static string S = S; }
```

This doesn't trigger a diagnostic with VS Professional 2013, .NET Framework 4.6.0.1055, Warning level 4.<sup>1</sup> Why not?

---

<sup>1</sup>To be fair with the compiler I assume that the initialization is well defined and assigns `S`' value in its default value state prior to the explicit initialization, i.e. null, to itself when the initialization is eventually performed; but it is almost certainly a coding error.

Comment: @eh the current compiler *does* know better, so no  need for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In recent versions of Visual Studio it says:

> Warning   CS1717  Assignment made to same variable; did you mean to assign something else?

So... update your IDE :)

Comment: Marc, I apologize -- I cannot reproduce my scenario with my version now and get the same warning as you do with VS2013, too. I don't want to undo all the changes since, so I cannot say what the difference is. There is  a small but non-zero possibility that I spaced and had assigned from a similar but different static variable.